# How can I create a Swing menu bar that appears at the very top of my program?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, kotlin, menubar

Coding Languages: I am coding in Kotlin with Swing, but I can transcode it to Kotlin if you provide any Java code. I know both Kotlin and Java so I will be able to understand either. Additionally, I am coding my application in Swing with at this stage, no libraries.

I want to create a menu bar for my application at the very top of the application, in the top bar. I have searched for this and found various menu bar tutorials but every single one of them resulted in a bar with options **below** both the application icon and the applications minimize, maximize, and close buttons.

Even the official [Java Documentation on the matter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) only results in the image below.
[image: An image of the menu bar below the top bar of the application]

There are many other tutorials, but all of them only show how to create a menu bar below the actual top of the application. I thought that this was just because apps can't change what's on the top bar, but then I realized that Chrome, the very application I am using right now, doesn't just show a title, icon, and three buttons. It has a whole tab system. All of the Microsoft Office applications have extra buttons of the top bar, although they have an additional bar for menu items anyways. A screenshot is provided, showing an autosave button and a few extras. (I removed my details)
[image: A screenshot of Microsoft Word]

For a perfect example of what I want mine to look like, I've provided a screenshot of the Jetbrains' IntelliJ IDEA. IntelliJ was coded in Swing with no libraries, as far as I know, so whatever they did must be possible with just Swing. I want a bunch of options to be on the very top bar, just like in the screenshot below.
[image: A screenshot of IntelliJ IDEA]

Just in case there is any ambiguity on what I am talking about, I want my top bar, the one with the close button, maximize and minimize buttons, icon, and app title to also include other options. In IntelliJ's case, the inclusion of File, Edit, View, Navigate, etc. Based on what my application is for, I might include File, Save, Undo, Options, and Help all with dropdowns to select items in lists. (Ex. File might have Open, Open Recent, New, Settings, etc. in a dropdown menu after hovering over it)

Any links to how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Again, I am coding my project in Kotlin, but I know Java as well so I will take answers from both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *top bar* of a `JFrame` in *Swing* is known as a *title bar*. It is part of what's referred to as the *decorations* of the `JFrame`. The border of the `JFrame` is also part of the decorations.

What you can do is remove the decorations. Then the menu bar will appear as though it is the *top bar*. Removing the decorations is achieved by calling method [`setUndecorated(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated-boolean-). Removing the decorations also means that the `JFrame` cannot be moved or resized since it doesn't have a border or title bar. And because there is no title bar there is also no X button that you can click in order to close the `JFrame`. You can add code that will allow you to move and resize the `JFrame` but I don't think that is within the scope of your question. In any case you will find examples of how to do that on the Internet if that's relevant for you. You can, nonetheless, still close the `JFrame` via the keyboard by pressing the keys Alt+F4.

Here is a small *Swing* application that displays an empty, undecorated `JFrame` that has a menu.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class MenuTest implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;

    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
        frame.setSize(400, 350);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JMenu createEditMenu() {
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenuItem cutItem = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        editMenu.add(cutItem);
        JMenuItem copyItem = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        editMenu.add(copyItem);
        JMenuItem pasteItem = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        editMenu.add(pasteItem);
        return editMenu;
    }

    private JMenu createFileMenu() {
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New");
        fileMenu.add(newItem);
        JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        fileMenu.add(openItem);
        JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        fileMenu.add(saveItem);
        return fileMenu;
    }

    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(createFileMenu());
        menuBar.add(createEditMenu());
        return menuBar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.put("MenuBar.background", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new MenuTest());
    }
}
```

Comment: So essentially I remove the top bar entirely and then recreate one where I have further control over it. That will work. I just wonder the UIManager is. Is setting the color through that method common? I just typed menuBar.background = Color.LIGHT_GRAY (Kotlin code) and it worked fine. Apart from that though, this solution looks like just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Abra’s answer is what you want essentially. But note that by removing the decorations of your application you will loose native features!

- e.g. on Windows aero snap, taskbar preview etc. will be disabled.

and the applications isn’t cross platform any more:

- you will need to supply different implementations of the title bar based on the operating system.
- Forcing the menu bar to be in the window goes against the design
  approach of macOS apps.

Instead of implementing everything yourself you might want to check out [Darklaf](https://github.com/weisJ/darklaf) a Look And Feel which does what you want to achieve without loosing native features or cross platform visuals. (Disclaimer: I am the creator of it)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that right now I'm not actually building a real app as much as just trying to learn Swing so that I can start building apps. I know JavaFX but wanted to try something else. I haven't really mastered Swing so I am not packaging any apps and such. I might come back to this later when I do get a handle on Swing.

Answer (score 1):

the Look and Feel flatlaf almost perfectly recreates the IntelliJ interface at all levels with minimal effort.

https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/

`System.setProperty( "flatlaf.menuBarEmbedded", "false" );` will embed the menu bar.

This accomplishes far more than just embedding the menu bar, but if you're looking to create a more modern-feeling app overall, this might be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: As far as I know this only works on Windows 10+